# Funcionamiento de los Iteradores

Tags: python, iteradores

Tenía una duda sobre el funcionamiento de los iteradores en python. La duda en cuestión es la siguiente:

Podemos considerar en los iteradores, que en el método mágico `__iter__` se almacenan, crean, por lo general, estructuras genéricas, tales como contadores que posteriormente emplearemos en el método mágico `__next__`, almacenando por tanto, en este último método estructuras más "complejas" de tratamiento y condiciones.

Answer (score 1):

En Python para que un objeto sea un iterador debe cumplir con el llamado "protocolo iterador". Vamos a partir de tres conceptos íntimamente relacionados:

- Un **iterable** es un objeto que implementa el método `__iter__` o que implemente el método `__getitem__` de forma que puede tomar indices consecutivos empezando desde 0 lanzando una excepción `IndexError` ante índices inválidos. Esto implica que pueden ser siempre pasados al built-in `iter` para que retorne un iterador a partir del mismo.
- Un **iterador** es un objeto que además implementa el método `__next__`, el cual al ser llamado retorna el siguiente item del mismo o la excepción `StopIteration` si el iterador ha sido "consumido".
- Un **ciclo `for - in`** siempre empieza llamando al método `__iter__` del cual obtiene un iterador a partir del iterable de turno. A partir del mismo, en cada iteración llama a su método `__next__` para obtener el item correspondiente hasta que se obtiene una excepción `StopIteration`.

  Si tenemos por ejemplo:

  ```
  lista = [1, 2, 3, 4]
  for n in lista:
      print(n)
  ```

  podríamos decir que es "equivalente" a:

  ```
  lista = [1, 2, 3, 4]

  loop_iter = lista.__iter__()
  while True:
      try:
          print(loop_iter.__next__())
      except StopIteration:
          break
  ```

Por lo tanto, en esencia, una clase para conformar un iterador y cumplir con el protocolo iterador debe implementar dos métodos "mágicos":

- **`__iter__`:** debe retorna siempre un iterador y su principal razón de ser es que es el punto de partida de los ciclos `for` o de cualquier método de iteración como es el desempaquetado de tuplas o `map`.

  Si bien puede actuar como una especie de inicializador (como lo es `__init__`), dado que es ejecutado cuando el iterador es invocado, permitiendo definir valores iniciales necesarios para el funcionamiento del iterador y el mantenimiento de su estado, **su función primordial es crear y retornar un iterador a partir del objeto iterable del que es método**. Lo anterior implica que si el objeto es un iterador en si mismo, por lógica, su método `__iter__` debe retornar al propio objeto sin más.

  Esto último permite que que `iter()` pueda recibir iteradores parcialmente recorridos, lo cual es muy útil en ciertos casos, por ejemplo cuando iteramos sobre un archivo y queremos descartar la primera línea antes de procesarlo en un `for`.

  > ```
  > >>> lista = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  > >>> lista_iter = iter(lista)
  > >>> next(lista_iter)
  > 1
  > >>> next(lista_iter)
  > 2
  > >>> for n in lista_iter:
  >         print(n)
  > 3
  > 4
  > 5
  > ```
- **`__next__`:** su razón de ser es **calcular cada item del iterador a partir del estado anterior del iterador**, bien en cada iteración de un ciclo `for` o en invocaciones mediante el builtin `next()`. Deberá además indicar que no hay más items disponibles lanzando la excepción `StopIteration`.

  Este método es esencial para proporcionar una de las características más potentes e interesantes de **los iteradores, son perezosos**. Esto quiere decir que no se calcula un nuevo item hasta que este no es solicitado mediante una llamada a  `__next__`. Esto permite por ejemplo ahorrar gran cantidad de recursos al no tener que calcular y almacenar todos los items en memoria desde un inicio.

  Por lo tanto, debe incluir toda la lógica necesaria para obtener el estado actual del iterador,  generar un nuevo item y actualizar el estado del mismo por si hay nuevos requerimientos de items.

Answer (score 0):

Bienvenida a StackOverflow en Español. Creo que tengo tu respuesta. Entiendo que tu pregunta es acerca de función `iter()` a pesar de que no está bien planteada ([¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)).

---

Toda la información será explicada directamente desde los documentos [Build-in iterator types](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types). Para tener un entendimiento completo es necesario saber lo siguiente:

**container.__iter__():**

> Python admite un concepto de iteración sobre contenedores. Esto se implementa utilizando dos métodos distintos; Estos se utilizan para permitir que las clases definidas por el usuario admitan la iteración. Las secuencias, que se describen a continuación con más detalle, siempre admiten los métodos de iteración.

En python, el concepto de *iteración* se concede como un *objeto* que contiene otros objectos (como `list` o `dict`), es decir, es un *container* (contenedor) que se comporta una interfaz.

`container.__iter__()`: retorna un objeto iterador adherido al *protocolo-iterador*, esto significa que tiene una funcion `next()`

> los propios objetos iteradores son necesarios para admitir los siguientes dos métodos, que juntos forman el protocolo iterador:

1. `iterator.__iter__()`
2. `iterator.__next__()`

---

**Lo anterior también se puede explicar con el siguiente ejemplo secuencial:**

La mayoría de los objetos contenedores pueden ser recorridos utilizando la sentencia `for`. La sentencia `for` llama al método `__iter__()` del objeto contenedor. La función devuelve un objeto `iterador` que define el método `__next__()` que accede a los elementos del contenedor de a uno por vez.

Haciendo un paréntesis `()` definimos los *métodos mágicos* que son aquellos que comienzan y terminan con *guión bajo* `_` que no están pensados para ser invocados manualmente, sino que son llamados por Python en situaciones particulares.

Por ejemplo, `__next__()` es un *método mágico* que lo suele llamar el `for`; `for` pide los elementos al contendor llamando al método `__next__()`, y cuando no hay más elementos, `__next__()` levanta una excepción (`Exception`) de tipo `StopIteration`, que le indica a al `for` que no tiene más elementos por recorrer y, por tanto, debe terminar.

---

**Simulación de la iteración del `for`:**

```py
lista = [1, 2, 3] # declaramos una lista con números de tipo enteros (int)
iterador = iter(lista)  # obtenemos el iterador de la lista

# mostramos el objeto iterador y utilizamos el next cuatro veces para que en el último retorne StopIteration
def display():
  return iterador,  next(iterador), next(iterador), next(iterador), next(iterador)

print(display())


-------------------------
(<list_iterator object at 0x7f9a8824cc40>, 1, 2, 3)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 8, in <module>    print(display())
  File "main.py", line 6, in display    return iterador,  next(iterador), next(iterador), next(iterador), next(iterador)
StopIteration
```

**Entendiendo la iteración desde una clase:**

```py
class Iterator():
  '''retorna los elementos de las posiciones pares de una lista'''
  # métodos magicos:

  # llama a crear una instancia a la clase iterator, guarda en una variable el iterable recibido como argumento y define una variable indice que comienza en 0
  def __init__(self, datos):
    self.datos = datos
    self.indice = 0

   def __iter__(self): # retorna un objeto que tenga definido en el método mágico __next__()
    return self 

  def __next__(self):  
    if self.indice >= len()self.datos): 
      raise StopIteration # levanta la excepción si el indice es mayor al tamaño recibido
    elemento = self.datos(self.indice) # mantiene el índice actual y le suma 2
    self.indice += 2
    return elemento
```