# ¿Se puede resetear un generador?

Tags: python, python-3.x, yield, generator

Acabo de conocer el concepto de Generador y estoy practicando con estos, la cosa es que he creado un generador que se le pasa una tupla y quiero coja el primer elemento de la `tupla` la cosa es que cuando lo llamo me devuelve `<generator object next_regla at 0x000001DEDEC566D8>` ,esto que significa?

```
tupla = (2,3,4,0) 
def next_regla(*tupla):
   for i in tupla:
       yield i
```

yo pensaba que me devolvía el primer valor de la tupla y cuando lo volviera a llamar, me devolviera el segundo valor de la tupla. Por ultimo, se podría resetear el generador, es decir, llamarlo 2 veces y en esas llamadas, que me arroje el primer y el segundo elemento y luego cuando lo quiera resetear el generador, cunado lo llame por 3 vez me arrojarme el valor el valor del índice 0.

1r llamada retorne: 2

2n llamada retorne: 3

resetear el generador

3r llamada retorne: 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La cadena `<generator object next_regla at 0x000001DEDEC566D8>` es la salida del método `__repr__` del objeto, simplemente indica que ese objeto es un generador alojado en esa dirección de memoria.

```
    def next_regla(tupla):
       for i in tupla:
           yield i

    tupla = (2, 3, 4, 0)
```

> ```
> >>> gen = next_regla(tupla)
> >>> gen
> <generator object next_regla at 0x7fd921b1a040>
> ```

Ten en cuenta que `next_regla(tupla)` no obtiene ningún item del generador, eso simplemente instancia un nuevo objeto generador.

De forma muy somera, un generador implementa el [protocolo iterador](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/335234/15089), un generador es un iterador, es de hecho una forma simplificada de crear un iterador mediante una función que tiene uno o varios estamentos `yield.` Los generadores también pueden ser creados mediante expresiones generadoras, de sintaxis similar a las listas por compresión:

> ```
> >>> gen = (n for n in tupla)
> >>> gen
> <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fd921b1a0b0>
> ```

Cuando se llama a una función generadora, se retorna un objeto generador, pero sin ejecutar siquiera la función en si.
Cuando se llama a `next()` (`__next__`) por primera vez la función se ejecuta hasta que se topa con un `yield`, retorna el valor, pasa el control de nuevo al código que la llamó y muy importante, recuerda su estado.

En las subsiguientes llamadas a `next` continúa la ejecución dónde la dejó hasta toparse con otro `yield`, si ésto no ocurre se lanza una excepción `StopIteration`.

Para obtener los items de un generador debes hacer una de éstas cosa:

- Iterar sobre él con un ciclo `for` explícitamente:

  > ```
  > >>> gen = next_regla(tupla)
  >
  > >>> for item in gen:
  >         print(item)
  > 2
  > 3
  > 4
  > 0
  > ```
- Usar `next()`:

  > ```
  > >>> gen = next_regla(tupla)
  > >>> next(gen)
  > 2
  > >>> next(gen)
  > 3
  > >>> next(gen)
  > 4
  > >>> next(gen)
  > 0
  > >>> next(gen)
  > Traceback (innermost last):
  >   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  > StopIteration
  > ```
- Crear algún contenedor a partir de él (iteración implícita)

  > ```
  > >>> gen = next_regla(tupla)
  > >>> list(gen)
  > [2, 3, 4, 0]
  > ```

### ¿Se puede resetear un generador?

Técnicamente no, en general no podemos volver hacia atrás en un generador. Cada llamada a su método `__next__` "consume" un item del mismo, una iteración del ciclo que generalmente es el núcleo de la función generadora:

> ```
> >>> gen = next_regla(tupla)
> >>> next(gen)
> 2
> >>> next(gen)
> 3
> >>> for item in gen:
>         print(item)
> 4
> 0
> ```

Lo que si puedes hacer, es simplemente "instanciar" un nuevo generador.

No obstante, dado el dinamismo de Python y su flexibilidad, hay muy pocos "nunca", aunque podemos terminar con cosas muy extrañas o barbaridares. Por ejemplo, por poder podemos usar el método `send` para "resetear" nuestro generador:

```
def next_regla(tupla):
    len_tupla = len(tupla)
    i = 0
    while i < len_tupla:
        val = (yield tupla[i])
        if val == 'reset':
            i = 0
        else:
            i += 1
```

> ```
> >>> tupla = (2, 3, 4, 0) 
> >>> gen = next_regla(tupla)
>
> >>> next(gen)
> 2
> >>> next(gen)
> 3
> >>> gen.send("reset")
> 2
> >>> next(gen)
> 3
> >>> next(gen)
> 4
> >>> gen.send("reset")
> 2
> >>> next(gen)
> 3
> >>> next(gen)
> 4
> >>> next(gen)
> 0
> >>> next(gen)
> Traceback (innermost last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> StopIteration
> ```

El uso de `send` básicamente convierte a la función generadora en una corrutina, que muy a grandes rasgos, es una función que puede suspender su ejecución y posteriormente restaurarla dónde la dejó (como una función generadora), pero en éstas pausas puede haber un intercambio de datos **en ambos sentidos**.

`next(gen)` equivale realmente a `gen.send(None)`.